# Chrome SASS source maps with SASS files not publicly accessible

Tags: google-chrome, sass, source-maps

I'm having the following issues on a project I'm working on. We've set it up so that source assets (scss files, etc) are not publicly accessible. I'm compiling the files into a publicly accessible directory along with the source map file.

Is there anyway to allow chrome to access these source files so that I can view sourcemap info? I'm working locally.

Answer (score 0):

For source maps to work you need to be accessing your site/app from a server. View your project on your favorite flavor or LAMP/XAMPP/WAMP or other local server configuration.

[Source](https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/css-preprocessors#toc-requirements)